# GeoIP install failure, advice needed

Tags: geolocation, geo, geoip

Several hours of frustration here and looking to see if anyone has any advice.

I'm trying to install GeoIP vie Homebrew and receive the following error just prior to the install finishing:

"Error: The linking step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link geoip'"

brew link geoip returned this error:

"Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/geoip/1.4.8/etc/GeoIP.conf.default
/usr/local/etc is not writable. You should change its permissions."

I also tried "sudo link geoip" and recieved this error:

"Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew link'"

I'm not entirely familiar with permissions and such and was wondering what I needed to do from the command line to get this to link properly. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. This script fixes the permissions issue:

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/raw/768518/fix_homebrew.rb)"